# What does this symbol () => mean in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

You can see "(...)=>" symbol in the very first line of this code:

```
const server = http.createServer((req,res) => {
       res.statusCode = 200;
       res.setHeader('content-type', 'text/plain');
       res.end('Hello World');
    });
```

Comment: ES6 arrow function

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/he/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: Why is this being downvoted?  I think that it is a very good question.

Comment: @JonTrauntvein because people are dicks

Comment: becasue lack of research. Very common dupe

Comment: @Kevin B Then help a new user by at least including links to the duplicated questions.  Silently down-voting will do neither him nor the community any good at all!

Comment: @JonTrauntvein the question is closed as said duplicate... Do you not see the huge banner in the question pointing to the dupe?

Comment: @Kevin B The question was not closed when I first looked at it and I still believe that you will accomplish nothing without at least referencing said duplicates!

Answer (score 11):

It's an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), newly defined in ES6.

> An arrow [function expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function) has a shorter syntax than a function expression and does not bind its own [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this), [arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments), [super](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/super), or [new.target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new.target). Arrow functions are always [anonymous](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name). These function expressions are best suited for non-method functions, and they cannot be used as constructors.

---

They are often just a shorter way of writing the anonymous function `function () {}`, with which you may already be familiar.

These pieces of code do the same thing:

1. ```
   setTimeout(function () {
     console.log("Hey");
   }, 1000);
   ```
2. ```
   setTimeout(() => {
     console.log("Hey");
   }, 1000);
   ```

This means that in your example `http.createServer` is accepting one argument, a function which itself takes two arguments.

---

Arrow functions are not equivalent to `function () {}` anonymous functions, `function () {}` binds its own `this`, for example.

Comment: or, just don't because that's already *well* covered on the dupe.

Comment: I'm sure you know the difference, but too much simplification leads to misunderstanding very easily. It's like saying DOM getters return an array, and in the next question asker posts, they ask "why my `array.pop()` doesn't work".

Comment: @Teemu but I haven't said that, I just hadn't specified fully the difference between them. I don't feel I did anything wrong.

Comment: @Teemu I understand what you're saying, but I don't think it's quite so extreme a case. I said "Essentially, these pieces of code do the same thing." Which was true. It just can't be applied to all cases.

Comment: They do the same thing, but are not equivalent. you didn't say they were equivalent, so you're not wrong

Answer (score 9):

It is an ES6 Arrow function:

```
(req, res) => {}
```

is equivalent to:

```
function(req, res){}
```

Comment: why did this get downvoted? It is actually correct, it isn´t lambda in JS as some might think, comparing it to other languages

Comment: it's a simplification of what arrow functions in JS are. They are more than just a shorthand for anonymous functions. You could even go so far as saying the two snippets in this answer are not equivalent.