# javascript pagination internet explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

i have this piece of code, taken from codepen used for paginate a large list of items in HTML.

Unfortunately, it works well for Chrome but no for explorer 11.

Can anyone help me fixing it for ie?

probably could depend on the arrow function => newly defined in ES6, but when i change it using this example [ES6 Arrow function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41702205/what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-javascript), the pagination does not work

```js
// Returns an array of maxLength (or less) page numbers
// where a 0 in the returned array denotes a gap in the series.
// Parameters:
//   totalPages:     total number of pages
//   page:           current page
//   maxLength:      maximum size of returned array
function getPageList(totalPages, page, maxLength) {
    if (maxLength < 5) throw "maxLength must be at least 5";

    function range(start, end) {
        return Array.from(Array(end - start + 1), (_, i) => i + start); 
    }

    var sideWidth = maxLength < 9 ? 1 : 2;
    var leftWidth = (maxLength - sideWidth*2 - 3) >> 1;
    var rightWidth = (maxLength - sideWidth*2 - 2) >> 1;
    if (totalPages <= maxLength) {
        // no breaks in list
        return range(1, totalPages);
    }
    if (page <= maxLength - sideWidth - 1 - rightWidth) {
        // no break on left of page
        return range(1, maxLength-sideWidth-1)
            .concat([0])
            .concat(range(totalPages-sideWidth+1, totalPages));
    }
    if (page >= totalPages - sideWidth - 1 - rightWidth) {
        // no break on right of page
        return range(1, sideWidth)
            .concat([0])
            .concat(range(totalPages - sideWidth - 1 - rightWidth - leftWidth, totalPages));
    }
    // Breaks on both sides
    return range(1, sideWidth)
        .concat([0])
        .concat(range(page - leftWidth, page + rightWidth)) 
        .concat([0])
        .concat(range(totalPages-sideWidth+1, totalPages));
}

$(function () {
    // Number of items and limits the number of items per page
    var numberOfItems = $("#jar .content").length;
    var limitPerPage = 2;
    // Total pages rounded upwards
    var totalPages = Math.ceil(numberOfItems / limitPerPage);
    // Number of buttons at the top, not counting prev/next,
    // but including the dotted buttons.
    // Must be at least 5:
    var paginationSize = 7; 
    var currentPage;

    function showPage(whichPage) {
        if (whichPage < 1 || whichPage > totalPages) return false;
        currentPage = whichPage;
        $("#jar .content").hide()
            .slice((currentPage-1) * limitPerPage, 
                    currentPage * limitPerPage).show();
        // Replace the navigation items (not prev/next):            
        $(".pagination li").slice(1, -1).remove();
        getPageList(totalPages, currentPage, paginationSize).forEach( item => {
            $("<li>").addClass("page-item")
                     .addClass(item ? "current-page" : "disabled")
                     .toggleClass("active", item === currentPage).append(
                $("<a>").addClass("page-link").attr({
                    href: "javascript:void(0)"}).text(item || "...")
            ).insertBefore("#next-page");
        });
        // Disable prev/next when at first/last page:
        $("#previous-page").toggleClass("disabled", currentPage === 1);
        $("#next-page").toggleClass("disabled", currentPage === totalPages);
        return true;
    }

    // Include the prev/next buttons:
    $(".pagination").append(
        $("<li>").addClass("page-item").attr({ id: "previous-page" }).append(
            $("<a>").addClass("page-link").attr({
                href: "javascript:void(0)"}).text("Prev")
        ),
        $("<li>").addClass("page-item").attr({ id: "next-page" }).append(
            $("<a>").addClass("page-link").attr({
                href: "javascript:void(0)"}).text("Next")
        )
    );
    // Show the page links
    $("#jar").show();
    showPage(1);

    // Use event delegation, as these items are recreated later    
    $(document).on("click", ".pagination li.current-page:not(.active)", function () {
        return showPage(+$(this).text());
    });
    $("#next-page").on("click", function () {
        return showPage(currentPage+1);
    });

    $("#previous-page").on("click", function () {
        return showPage(currentPage-1);
    });
});
```

Comment: I know it's not exactly what you want, but every time I have a problem with IE, I try to consider using Polyfills. -- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Polyfill

Comment: I tried using the Polyfill for the array.from function but instead of the number of the pages i got the three dots button disabled. it seems that this is the function that goes wrong :    function range(start, end) {
        return Array.from(Array(end - start + 1), (_, i) => i + start); 
    }

Comment: Arrow => function is not supported in IE browser. I suggest you to use Babel.js to transpile your ES 6 code to ES5 code which can work in IE and solve the arrow function errors for IE. Ref: https://babeljs.io/

Comment: Thanks @Deepak-MSFT i solved with https://babeljs.io/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrow => function is not supported in IE browser. I suggest you to use Babel.js to transpile your ES 6 code to ES5 code which can work in IE and solve the arrow function errors for IE. Ref: [babeljs.io](https://babeljs.io/)